# How to display data in a specific numbered position using php and mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a scenario like this:
I will take a number as input and will store in the database along with other information. And will display the data from the database as per the number position that have been taken as input. For example: if the input is 4, the display order will be in fourth position.
I want to make this using PHP/Mysql.
Thanks for the suggestions...

Comment: start writing some code dude..

Comment: Thanks Saurabh for the suggestion. But I just want to know how will I sort the data accordingly to the taken input position!!!

Comment: you can use ORDER BY for the same.. if you write some code we can help better. eg: SELECT * from Table ORDER BY position DESC; (assuming position is the column name of the position value).

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have field serial_number in your table iserted for serial by input, then firstlly you have to fetch table in array and then sort the table according to the serial number the code is like follow

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$sql="select * from sort.data";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$data=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $data[]=$row; 
}
echo '<br />content of data before sorting';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';

$final = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$item)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$key;$i++)
    {
        if($data[$i]['serial_number']>$data[$key]['serial_number'])
        {
            $temp = $data[$key];
            $data[$key] = $data[$i];
            $data[$i]   = $temp;
        }   
    }   
}
echo '<br />content of data after sorting';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

here lastly `$data` containing the sorted array as per your requirement then you applay the table and td on it for formatting

Answer (score 0):

as Saurabh Sinha commented. I am describing his comment.
store your input value in table such as position

```
$position = $_REQUEST['position']; // position submit by your form eg:4
```

insert record with position

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `your_table`(field1, field2,....,position) VALUES('$field1_value', '$field2_value',.....,'$position')");
```

now when ever you retrive your records and be sort according to the position. using `ORDER BY` like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE [YOUR CONDITIONS] ORDER BY position [DESC/ASC]";
```

in `[]` optional. 
eg : if you have no condition to apply and want to order in Descending use given query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` ORDER BY position DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks Satish for your help. This is not what I am actually looking for. If I am assigning position 4 for a set of data, those data will be displayed in fourth position in the list.